# Centered modal load spinner bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I want a modal load spinner and have based a test on Bootstrap 4's modal dialog box. However, I can't get the modal horizontally centered on the page. If possible, I would also like the modal to be with no borders and transparent (so it appears that only the spinner is hovering over the page)

```js
 function modal(){
       $('.modal').modal('show');
       setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('hejsan');
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
       }, 3000);
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="modal();">Open and close in 3 secs</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 48px">
            <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>I would like the <ul><li>spinner horizontally centered on page<li> the modal transparent without borders</ul></p>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apply this two classes:

```
.bd-example-modal-lg .modal-dialog{
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: calc(50% - 24px);
  }

  .bd-example-modal-lg .modal-dialog .modal-content{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
```

```js
function modal(){
       $('.modal').modal('show');
       setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('hejsan');
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
       }, 3000);
    }
```

```css
.bd-example-modal-lg .modal-dialog{
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: calc(50% - 24px);
  }
  
  .bd-example-modal-lg .modal-dialog .modal-content{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="modal();">Open and close in 3 secs</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 48px">
            <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>I would like the <ul><li>spinner horizontally centered on page<li> the modal transparent without borders</ul></p>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I've updated the jsbin with your css and put the spinner at 1/3 of the height of the page instead. Looks a bit better to me. https://jsbin.com/cezejuk/edit?html,output

Comment: For me, 02 customized make it perfect on Chrome 1) remove modal-content width, 2) fa-spinner has font-size 6rem

Answer (score 14):

Old post, I know, but this seems a cleaner option to me...

```js
function modal(){
       $('.modal').modal('show');
       setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('hejsan');
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
       }, 3000);
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="modal();">Open and close in 3 secs</button>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="spinnerModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered text-center" role="document">
        <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x w-100"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<p>I would like the <ul><li>spinner horizontally centered on page<li> the modal transparent without borders</ul></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 4.x using `d-flex` and `justify-content-center` classes.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="loadingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered d-flex justify-content-center" role="document">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove one more class. Because `modal-dialog` is a flex box.

`text-center` + `w-100` -> `justify-content-center`

```js
function modal(){
    $('.modal').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('completed');
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="modal();">Open and close in 3 secs</button>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered justify-content-center" role="document">
        <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<p>I would like the <ul><li>spinner horizontally centered on page<li> the modal transparent without borders</ul></p>
```